# Plotting n lines each second with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have to say that i am new to Gnuplot. 
I have a file with 3 columns of datas  and I managed plotting it with 
gnuplot "name.txt" obtaining a 3D graph. Now i would want to graph n lines of that txt each second. I read that it is possible if the file update itself each second but it is not my case. 
I have this file with datas that are calculated by a c++ program and represent the position of an object every  second . Is it possible to live update the Graph so that you can see n points plotted  each second ?
Until now I managed to do this byte Command :  splot "data.txt" every ::1::10 . With this Gnuplot draw n lines form  data.txt

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Done! The problem is that I don't know Gnuplot very much .

Comment: It is still not clear what you are aiming for.  If second 1 plots points 1-10, does second 2 plot contain 10 points 11-20 or 20 points 1-20?  Do the contents of the file remain unchanged, so that it can be read only once and then processed in pieces, or does the file need to be reread every second?   Do you want each set of points to be distinguishable from the previous set (e.g. different color, different symbol)?

Comment: The Second plot contains 20 points . The first 10 points plus the  ten points updated in the second second . The content of the file is the same . I would want to add the first 10 lines of datas in the first second and then other ten lines in the second later .

Comment: The file I use doesn't change in time

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility:

```
  do for [N=10:*:10] {
    splot 'name.txt' every 1::1::N using 1:2:3 with points
    pause 1.0
  }
```

Comment: Okay this works but doesn't do what i intended . I have this file with 3 columns of data and these are points in 3D and I want to graph them

Comment: Oops, sorry.  That should have been `splot`, not `plot`. Edited to show the 3D equivalent.

Comment: loops until it runs out of data.  As in "I don't know what the maximum is - just go till you reach the end".

Comment: I did : do for [N=1:1000:1] {
    splot 'data.txt' every 1::1::N using 1:2:3 with points
    pause 0.1
  }

Comment: But that command generates a new plot for each point rather than for each 10 points.   As to "*" I see you are correct that in this case the program starts printing warning messages rather than stopping cleanly when it runs out of data. That's a bug.